# RESTful pagination routes using will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have nested routes like this :

```
map.resources :foo do |foo|
  foo.resources :bar do |bar|
    bar.resources :baz
  end
end
```

i have list with pagination in the index action for each resource, i need to caches each of this pages, to do so i need the routes to be RESTful, how do i implements REFTful routes for it?

for example i want the route will be like this :

```
http://www.example.com/foo/:id/pages/:page_number
http://www.example.com/foo/:id/bar/:id/pages/:page_number
```

Comment: finally i use the old school way :
map.connect '/foo/:id/pages/:page', :controller => 'foo', :action => 'show', :method => :get

but i have to hack the will_paginate

Comment: This is exactly how I did it for my project.  It's not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I wrote my own LinkRenderer like this to fully use nested routes.

```
class PaginationListLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ViewHelpers::LinkRenderer


protected

  def page_number(page)
    unless page == current_page
      if !@options[:params][:url].to_s.empty?
        tag(:li, link(page, @options[:params][:url] + "?page=" + page.to_s))
      else
        tag(:li, link(page,  page, :rel => rel_value(page)))
      end
    else
      tag(:li, page, :class => "current")
    end
  end

  def previous_or_next_page(page, text, classname)
    if page
      if !@options[:params][:url].to_s.empty?
        tag(:li, link(text, @options[:params][:url] + "?page=" + page.to_s, :class => classname))
      else
        tag(:li, link(text,  page, :rel => rel_value(page), :class => classname))
      end
      #tag(:li, link(text, page), :class => classname)
    else
      tag(:li, text, :class => classname + ' disabled')
    end
  end

  def html_container(html)
    tag(:ul, html, container_attributes)
  end

end
```

Then you have to call will_paginate with this parameters:

```
<%= will_paginate :params => { :url => project_task_lists_path(@project) }, :renderer => PaginationListLinkRenderer %>
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5):

create custom_link_renderer.rb in app/helpers/

```
class CustomLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::LinkRenderer
  def page_link(page, text, attributes = {})
    @template.link_to text, "#{@template.url_for(@url_params)}/pages/#{page}", attributes
  end
end
```

add this line to `config/environment.rb`

```
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:renderer] = 'CustomLinkRenderer'
```